# QUERY_TIMEOUT exception in test class

Tags: apex, unit-test

I have written a test class with a mock callout for the trigger but when I'm running it it's throwing the QUERY_TIMEOUT exception. How can I fix this issue?

```
@isTest
public class TestStatusIO_UpdateSubScriberStatusIO {

    public class UpdateSubscriberCalloutMock implements HttpCalloutMock{
        public HttpResponse respond(HttpRequest req){
            HttpResponse res = new HttpResponse();
            res.setHeader('Content-Type','application/json');
            res.setStatus('OK');
            res.setBody('{"status": {"error": "no","message": "Successfully updated subscriber"},"result": "null"}');
            res.setStatusCode(200);
            return res;
        }
    }    
    
    @isTest
    public static void testUpdateSubscriber(){
         Account acc=new Account();
        acc.Name='Test Account 1';
        insert acc;
        
        Contact cont2=new Contact();
        cont2.LastName='TEST CONTACT 2';
        cont2.AccountId=acc.Id;
        cont2.Email='test@csl2.com';
        cont2.Status_IO_Id__c='46671rsrefsu87483fdf';
        cont2.Position__c='Accounts';
        insert cont2;
        
        Campaign cmp=new Campaign();
        String recordTypeId=Schema.SObjectType.Campaign.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('Status IO Campaign').getRecordTypeId();
        cmp.Name='Sample Campaign';
        cmp.RecordTypeId=recordTypeId;
        cmp.Status_IO_Id__c='6290d6f34aa0eb0531fffbf7';
        cmp.Status_IO_Component_Ids__c='62600f07f69a9104dcf7e34d';
        insert cmp;
        
CampaignMember members=new CampaignMember();
        members.CampaignId=cmp.Id;
        members.ContactId=cont2.Id;
        Test.startTest();
        Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, new UpdateSubscriberCalloutMock());

            insert members;
       
        Test.stopTest();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please update your question with the exception and the stack trace. Most probably the timeout maybe occuring after the insert DML

Comment: it was due to incorrect JSON response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was because of an incorrect JSON body returning from the mock callout class. It worked when the response is changed to the desire response for the Apex class.

Comment: can share the incorrect JSON for people who want to see what to watch out for in future?